# D3.js - Data From CSV Not Displaying, Static Data Will

Tags: javascript, csv, svg, d3.js

When I use static data (the first dataset variable, identified as ATTEMPT #1 in the comments) the bar chart will display properly on the page.  However, when I read data in from the CSV file (commenting out first dataset variable and remove the commented out code that follows) nothing will display on the page.  And I don't get any errors in the console.

Here's the inspection of ATTEMPT #1 in the console, so you can see the two dataset variables are of a similar format:

```
$ dataset.length;
51
$ dataset[0];
[5, "WA"]
```

Here's the inspection of ATTEMPT #2 in the console:

```
$ dataset.length;
50
$ dataset[0];
[35.6, "Alabama"]
```

Here is the **/index.html** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: An HTML div tooltip</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

            rect:hover {
                fill: orange;
            }

            #tooltip {
                position: absolute;
                width: 200px;
                height: auto;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: white;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                pointer-events: none;
            }

            #tooltip.hidden {
                display: none;
            }

            #tooltip p {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px;
                line-height: 20px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
            <p><strong id="tool_header">State</strong>&nbsp;State</p>
            <p><span id="value">100</span>&nbsp;Per Inc Per Capita (000)</p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 600;
            var h = 250;

            // ATTEMPT #1 - Displays correctly
            var dataset = [ [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"]];

            /* ATTEMPT #2 - Won't display anything
            var dataset = [];

            // Save state info object into dataset array
            d3.csv("2012_PersonalIncomePerCapitaByState.csv", function(d) {

                // Store state and income (in 1,000's)
                for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                    dataset.push([Math.round( parseInt( d[i].Income ) / 100 ) / 10, d[i].State]);
                }
            });
            */

            var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                            .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                            .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

            var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                            .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; }) / 1.2, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; }) * 1.05])
                            .range([0, h]);

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            //Create bars
            svg.selectAll("rect")
               .data(dataset)
               .enter()
               .append("rect")
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i);
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d[0]);
               })
               .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
               .attr("height", function(d) {
                    return yScale(d[0]);
               })
               .attr("fill", function(d) {
                    return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d[0] * 10) + ")";
               })
               .on("mouseover", function(d) {

                    //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
                    var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
                    var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) / 2 + h / 2;

                    //Update the tooltip position and value
                    d3.select("#tooltip")
                        .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                        .style("top", yPosition + "px")                     
                        .select("#value")
                        .text(d[0]);

                    d3.select("#tooltip")
                        .select("#tool_header")
                        .text(d[1]);

                    //Show the tooltip
                    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

               })
               .on("mouseout", function() {

                    //Hide the tooltip
                    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);

               })
               .on("click", function() {
                    sortBars();
               });

            //Define sort order flag
            var sortOrder = false;

            //Define sort function
            var sortBars = function() {

                //Flip value of sortOrder
                sortOrder = !sortOrder;

                svg.selectAll("rect")
                   .sort(function(a, b) {
                        if (sortOrder) {
                            return d3.ascending(a, b);
                        } else {
                            return d3.descending(a, b);
                        }
                    })
                   .transition()
                   .delay(function(d, i) {
                       return i * 50;
                   })
                   .duration(1000)
                   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                        return xScale(i);
                   });

            };          

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the **2012_PersonalIncomePerCapitaByState.csv** file:

```
State,Income
Alabama,35625
Alaska,46778
Arizona,35979
Arkansas,34723
California,44980
Colorado,45135
Connecticut,58908
Delaware,41940
Florida,40344
Georgia,36869
Hawaii,44024
Idaho,33749
Illinois,44815
Indiana,36902
Iowa,42126
Kansas,41835
Kentucky,35041
Louisiana,39413
Maine,39481
Maryland,51971
Massachusetts,54687
Michigan,37497
Minnesota,46227
Mississippi,33073
Missouri,39049
Montana,37370
Nebraska,43143
Nevada,37361
New Hampshire,47058
New Jersey,53628
New Mexico,35079
New York,52095
North Carolina,37049
North Dakota,51893
Ohio,39289
Oklahoma,39006
Oregon,38786
Pennsylvania,43616
Rhode Island,44990
South Carolina,34266
South Dakota,43659
Tennessee,37678
Texas,41471
Utah,34601
Vermont,42994
Virginia,47082
Washington,45413
West Virginia,34477
Wisconsin,40537
Wyoming,48670
```

**Can you help me figure out why I can't get the values from the CSV file to display?**  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you run the code as posted, nothing will display because `d3.csv` is an asynchronous callback. That is, the code after that is executed immediately, before the data is actually defined. Try putting all the code inside `d3.csv`.

Comment: Wow! Amateur mistake, thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question (based on Lars Kotthoff's advice): move all code into the callback of the d3.csv() function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3: An HTML div tooltip</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

            rect:hover {
                fill: orange;
            }

            #tooltip {
                position: absolute;
                width: 200px;
                height: auto;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: white;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                pointer-events: none;
            }

            #tooltip.hidden {
                display: none;
            }

            #tooltip p {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px;
                line-height: 20px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">
            <p><strong id="tool_header">State</strong>&nbsp;State</p>
            <p><span id="value">100</span>&nbsp;Per Inc Per Capita (000)</p>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            //Width and height
            var w = 600;
            var h = 250;

            // ATTEMPT #1 - Displays correctly
            //var dataset = [ [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"], [5, "WA"], [6, "OR"], [3, "CA"]];


            //ATTEMPT #2 - Won't display anything
            var dataset = [];

            // Save state info object into dataset array
            d3.csv("2012_PersonalIncomePerCapitaByState.csv", function(d) {

                // Store state and income (in 1,000's)
                for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
                    dataset.push([Math.round( parseInt( d[i].Income ) / 100 ) / 10, d[i].State]);
                }


                var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                                .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
                                .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);

                var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                                .domain([d3.min(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; }) / 1.2, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; }) * 1.05])
                                .range([0, h]);

                //Create SVG element
                var svg = d3.select("body")
                            .append("svg")
                            .attr("width", w)
                            .attr("height", h);

                //Create bars
                svg.selectAll("rect")
                   .data(dataset)
                   .enter()
                   .append("rect")
                   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                        return xScale(i);
                   })
                   .attr("y", function(d) {
                        return h - yScale(d[0]);
                   })
                   .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                   .attr("height", function(d) {
                        return yScale(d[0]);
                   })
                   .attr("fill", function(d) {
                        return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d[0] * 10) + ")";
                   })
                   .on("mouseover", function(d) {

                        //Get this bar's x/y values, then augment for the tooltip
                        var xPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("x")) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
                        var yPosition = parseFloat(d3.select(this).attr("y")) / 2 + h / 2;

                        //Update the tooltip position and value
                        d3.select("#tooltip")
                            .style("left", xPosition + "px")
                            .style("top", yPosition + "px")                     
                            .select("#value")
                            .text(d[0]);

                        d3.select("#tooltip")
                            .select("#tool_header")
                            .text(d[1]);

                        //Show the tooltip
                        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", false);

                   })
                   .on("mouseout", function() {

                        //Hide the tooltip
                        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);

                   })
                   .on("click", function() {
                        sortBars();
                   });

                //Define sort order flag
                var sortOrder = false;

                //Define sort function
                var sortBars = function() {

                    //Flip value of sortOrder
                    sortOrder = !sortOrder;

                    svg.selectAll("rect")
                       .sort(function(a, b) {
                            if (sortOrder) {
                                return d3.ascending(a, b);
                            } else {
                                return d3.descending(a, b);
                            }
                        })
                       .transition()
                       .delay(function(d, i) {
                           return i * 50;
                       })
                       .duration(1000)
                       .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                            return xScale(i);
                       });

                };


            });


        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it displaying the data? For me it doesn't display anything! :(

Comment: Oh, it works! On Chrome is doesn't load the data, but it works in Firefox!